# How does socket.io work with multiple instances which were deployed by docker ？

Tags: docker, websocket, socket.io

I create a server and bind socket.io on it

```
const express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

io = io.listen(server);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('user connected', socket.id)
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(socket.id, 'message: ' + msg);
   });
});

server.listen(9999)
```

it's ok when I deploy 1 instance on docker (I use docker swarm and docker stack),
while if I set the deploy replicas

this's my compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
  image: socket:v2
  ports:
    - "5000:9999"
    command: node index.js
    deploy:
    replicas: 2
```

I meet some problems, when send message to server,
server1 show connected, and show got messages,
but next time I send, server2 show got messages

How can I make it to be 'which server I connected is which server I send messages to'?

Comment: I think you need to apply and configure Sticky sessions, you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494431/sticky-and-non-sticky-sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). which is an Automated Nginx proxy for Docker containers using docker-gen.

**Usage**

To run it:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Then start any containers you want proxied with an env var `VIRTUAL_HOST=subdomain.youdomain.com`

```
$ docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com
```

> The containers being proxied must expose the port to be proxied,
>   either by using the EXPOSE directive in their Dockerfile or by using
>   the `--expose` flag to docker run or docker create.
>
> Provided your DNS is setup to forward `foo.bar.com` to the host
>   running nginx-proxy, the request will be routed to a container with
>   the `VIRTUAL_HOST env` var set.

With Docker-compose you can try this example

Docker Compose

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local
```

Here `jwilder/whoami` will be proxied by `jwilder/nginx-proxy` as its specified `VIRTUAL_HOST`

You can read more about jwilder/nginx-proxy [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) and [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/pull/299)

Also, you can check this [docker-compose-scale-with-sticky-sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739344/docker-compose-scale-with-sticky-sessions)

You can check the above example

```
docker-compose up
```

Then run

```
curl -H "Host: whoami.local" localhost
```

You will see one container ID in every response

Now, its time to scale

```
docker-compose scale whoami=3
```

Now see the screenshot response from a different container.

[image]

To work with the sticky session you can use tpcwang's fork allows you to use the `IP_HASH` directive on a container level to enable sticky sessions.

If you are interested in built-in feature then you can try [Implement persistent (sticky) sessions](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/interlock/usage/sessions/)

> You can publish a service and configure the proxy for persistent
>   (sticky) sessions using:

- Cookies
- IP hashing

**IP Hashing**

> The following example shows how to configure sticky sessions using
>   client IP hashing. This is not as flexible or consistent as cookies
>   but enables workarounds for some applications that cannot use the
>   other method. When using IP hashing, reconfigure Interlock proxy to
>   use host mode networking, because the default ingress networking mode
>   uses SNAT, which obscures client IP addresses.

Create an overlay network so that service traffic is isolated and secure:

```
$> docker network create -d overlay demo
```

> Create a service with the cookie to use for sticky sessions using IP
>   hashing:

```
$> docker service create \
    --name demo \
    --network demo \
    --detach=false \
    --replicas=5 \
    --label com.docker.lb.hosts=demo.local \
    --label com.docker.lb.port=8080 \
    --label com.docker.lb.ip_hash=true \
    --env METADATA="demo-sticky" \
    ehazlett/docker-demo
```

> Interlock detects when the service is available and publishes it. When
>   tasks are running and the proxy service is updated, the application is
>   available via http://demo.local and is configured to use sticky
>   sessions: